# adding multiple overlay items on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to mark with push pin image on more than one places on google map using overlayitem class..OR in simple how to add more than one overlay items on map..

as of now i can only mark a single place by overriding draw method of mapoverlay subclass...
here is my code

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-24, null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw as many things as you like in the draw() method so just iterate over all the points you have in a loop and draw them one by one.

Comment: yes i was knowing this but i  took some time to realize exactly..ok thanks for your suggestion..